# How can I hide the up and down arrow and the placeholder text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design

[Click here to see the problem with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j45x.jpg)

How can I hide the up and down arrow and the placeholder text '(mm/dd/yy)'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS to remove the up and down arrows. They are shown in Chrome:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Remove the `placeholder` attribute from the input:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

Comment: Where are the to mm/dd/yyyy coming from? Can you post some HTML-Code?